# Is there a shorthand for <cfoutput>

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

It's just such a long tag and I use it so much.

For example

`<input name="LastName" <cfoutput> value="#FORM.LastName#" </cfoutput> />`

becomes

`<input name="LastName" <?> value="#FORM.LastName#" </?> />`

Maybe I'm just asking for too much.

Comment: Just create a command/snippet/macro/shortcut/whatever in your editor ;-)

Comment: My issue isn't with typing it itself, dreamweaver puts it in fast enough when I hit tab. I just don't like how much space it takes up when I look at the code.

Comment: Yes there is, <cfinput>, at least for that example.

Comment: Instead of wrapping every time you output each variable with it, you could just wrap the whole page, once.

Comment: @PatrickSchomburg this has prompted some thought from me, via my blog:  http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2014/07/gday-i-was-thinking-about-this.html

Comment: `cfinput` is never the correct answer. Ever.

Comment: I agree that I don't like cfinput. And I don't wrap tiny pieces of code like that usually, I just needed a quick and dirty example.

Comment: @duncan: Isn't that a bad idea that might generate extraneous output into the page source? Admittedly this might have been fixed in newer versions of CF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope `<cfoutput>` is all you get. For the tag syntax anyway. You could switch to script syntax instead.

```
<cfoutput>
    <p>hello</p>
</cfoutput>
```

versus

```
<cfscript>
    writeOutput("<p>hello</p>");
</cfscript>
```

You could always add a short-cut (keystroke) to your editor of choice for the tag.

Answer (score 12):

Ideally, you wouldn't wrap such a small piece of code in a cfoutput. It really makes the code hard to read and maintain.

Instead, you should wrap larger and logical chunks of code in cfoutput. There's little additional overhead and it's much easier to read and maintain.

```
<cfoutput>
<form>
    <input value="#SomeVar#">
    <input value="#SomeVar#">
    <input value="#SomeVar#">
    <input value="#SomeVar#">
    <input value="#SomeVar#">
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfoutput>
    <form>
        <input name="LastName"  value="#FORM.LastName#"/>
    </form>    
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors when you add some explaination for your intension.